Server with 2 ip address change outgoing ip address
I have a server with a single eth port the primary ip address is assigned by dhcp.
I have a secondary ip address (failover ip) that I want to add and configure as outgoing ip address.
This is the default configuration:
[root@~]# ip a
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:7b:86:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 57.187.244.7/24 brd 57.187.244.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[root@~]# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 57.187.244.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 57.187.244.255
        inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe7b:8685  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:16:3e:7b:86:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        -- packet list

[root@~]# ip route list
default via 57.187.244.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
57.187.244.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 57.187.244.7 metric 100

[root@~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         57.187.244.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
57.187.244.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0

After adding the secondary ip address
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.245.21/32 -- used for L2L Tunnel
ifconfig eth0:2 74.23.66.82/24
The server is reachable using the ip address on eth0:2
But if i try to use specific network does not work.
# curl ifconfig.me
57.187.244.7
# curl --interface eth0 ifconfig.me
57.187.244.7
# curl --interface eth0:2 ifconfig.me
57.187.244.7

I tried to edit the default route
ip route add default via 57.187.244.1 src 74.23.66.82

[root@~]# ip route list
default via 57.187.244.1 dev eth0 src 74.23.66.82
default via 57.187.244.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
57.187.244.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 57.187.244.7 metric 100
74.23.66.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 74.23.66.82

ip route del default via 57.187.244.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
[root@~]# ip route list
default via 57.187.244.1 dev eth0 src 74.23.66.82
57.187.244.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 57.187.244.7 metric 100
74.23.66.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 74.23.66.82

Still the same result, server reachable from both ip addresses but outgoing ip still 57.x.x.x
I would like to change outgoing ip address from 57.187.244.7 to 74.23.66.82
I tried other solutions but without success. What am I missing here?
This is the final configuration
[root@~]# ip a
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:7b:86:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 57.187.244.7/24 brd 57.187.244.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.245.21/0 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global eth0:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 74.23.66.82/24 brd 74.23.66.255 scope global eth0:2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[root@~]# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 57.187.244.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 57.187.244.255
        inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe7b:8685  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:16:3e:7b:86:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        -- packet lists

eth0:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.245.21  netmask 0.0.0.0  broadcast 255.255.255.255
        ether fa:16:3e:7b:86:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

eth0:2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 74.23.66.82  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 74.23.66.255
        ether fa:16:3e:7b:86:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)


[root@~]# ip route list
default via 57.187.244.1 dev eth0 src 74.23.66.82
57.187.244.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 57.187.244.7 metric 100
74.23.66.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 74.23.66.82

[root@~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         57.187.244.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
57.187.244.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
74.23.66.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0


What happens if you specify the address, instead of the interface name, for --interface?

If this is a server, I would not be using DHCP to assign its IP address. Don't use ipconfig to add secondary IP addresses, use ip a add 192.168.245.21/32 dev eth0 instead. Even better, rather than assigning secondary IP addresses, bring up a the dummy interface or as many as you need instead & run some routing protocol within your network if needed.

On LInux, use ip command (iproute package)  and put multiple IPs on an interface or have multiple interfaces. Do not use  ifconfig and  eth0:1  aliases, those have been obsolete for many years.
